# I'm unable to save the asp.net(Application page) people editor control value in sharepoint 2013 people picker field

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created person or group column in sharepoint 2013 list and I have created asp.net application page in vs environment for sharepoint 2013..Problem is I have put people editor control in apllication page when I was attempting to save the people editor value to sharepoint person or group(people picker field)... I got error like String to SPUser convertion is not possible...could you please give suggestions to resolve this...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var peoplePicker = this."WhereYourControlAdded_Id".FindControl("PeoplePickerControlID") as PeopleEditor;
  //here you should find your people picker control


   PeopleEditor peoplePicker = value as PeopleEditor;
   if (peoplePicker != null && peoplePicker.CommaSeparatedAccounts.ToString() != "")
   {
    string[] userarray = peoplePicker.CommaSeparatedAccounts.ToString().Split(',');
    SPFieldUserValueCollection usercollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();

      for (int i = 0; i < userarray.Length; i++)
      {
          SPFieldUserValue usertoadd = ConvertLoginAccount(userarray[i]);
          usercollection.Add(usertoadd);
      }

        item[item.Fields[columnName].InternalName] = usercollection;
    }
    else
    {
        item[item.Fields[columnName].InternalName] = null;
    }




 public static SPFieldUserValue ConvertLoginAccount(string userid)
    {
        SPFieldUserValue uservalue = null;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPUser requireduser = web.EnsureUser(userid);
                    uservalue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, requireduser.ID, requireduser.LoginName);
                }
            }

        });
        return uservalue;
    }
```

Comment: ConvertLoginAccount function will solve your problem. I shared all code which worked for me.

Comment: Yes it helps me, I got solution

Comment: Your code is working for site owners, site members but visitors unable to create request...Getting Error like You don't have permissions for this site...could you please give me any suggestions.

Comment: I modified ConvertLoginAccount function for solving permissions problem.